# Viewing pdf under Ubuntu, need rulers

Tags: pdf

I need a little help with viewing pdf under Ubuntu.
Unfortunately, there are not many analogues of the adobe reader for this system.
In fact, all I need is a grid and rulers.
For example, my typical task is to open two documents and compare the location of text, elements, and so on.
For example, in an adobe reader - I can turn on the ruler and click on the desired mark on it, after that there will be a blue bar on the page in the right place.
Unfortunately, Under ubuntu I can not find anything similar.
The closest in functionality is qoppa pdf viewer.
Perhaps there are other options?
Thank you very much for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you seek, but might fit your purposes as well. There are some ruler tools in the software center, kruler (KDE desktop) and screenruler (for the GTK desktop, e.g. the standard Ubuntu desktop. These tools place a neat ruler on the screen, which you then can place. The ruler can be set to stay on top: it isn't by default.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much
Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem properly.
For example, my typical task is to open two documents and compare the location of text, elements, and so on using lines. Unfortunately, I can't do that with this tool.

Comment: OK, that is essential information that was not in your question. So I suggest editing your question to reflect that.